# PHP Mssql_connect return Resource id #3 in browser

Tags: php, sql-server, centos6

I'm trying connect Php in CentOS 6.9 to SQL Server in windows.
I've install php-mssql.

This is my index.php

```
<?php
    $link = mssql_connect('192.168.1.17', 'root', '123456');

    if (!$link)
        die('Unable to connect!');
    if (!mssql_select_db('user', $link))
        die('Unable to select database!');

    $result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM dbo.user');
    print_r($result);
    ?>
```

but it return **Resource id #3**.

What does that return mean? and how to make it show the data. Thanks

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

With `mssql_query()` you get a resource which can be used to get the data from the database.

Let's have a look at the documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php

There you get an example:

```
$version = mssql_query('SELECT @@VERSION');
$datensatz = mssql_fetch_array($version);
```

So for your question you have to fetch all the data with `mssql_fetch_array()` or `mssql_fetch_assoc()`

```
$result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM dbo.user');
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  print_r($row);
}
```

But for newer PHP version this will not work. mssql_... and mysql_... are deprecated and will be removed in PHP 7.

So use PDO (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: This is an English language site, you shouldn't link to documentation in German, unless that is the only one available.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari oh, my fault. i updated the answer with the english version

Answer (score 0):

It means that the query has been executed and returned a correct resource.

To print your data you have to use functions like

- [mssql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php)
- or [mssql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php)
- but better [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) (since those other two function have been removed in PHP 7.0.0)

---

A quick suggest to achieve it with PDO:

Class to connect (singleton)

```
class Database
{
    private static $host       = '192.168.1.17';
    private static $db_name    = '';
    private static $charset    = 'utf8';
    private static $username   = 'root';
    private static $password   = '123456';

    private static $instance    = null;


    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    /* ***** GET DSN ***** */
    private static function getDsn() {
        return "mssql:host=" . self::$host . ";dbname=" . self::$db_name . ";charset=" . self::$charset . "";
    }

    /* ***** PDO CONNECTION ***** */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if ( ! isset(self::$instance)) {
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO(self::getDsn(), self::$username, self::$password, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "<p>Fail to connect</p>";
//                 throw $e->getCode();
            }
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Then you just call the static method and run the query:

```
$conn  = Database::getInstance();
$stmt  = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM dbo.user');
res    = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($res);
```